# Are there disadvantages in putting code into Userforms instead of modules?

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, userform

**Are there disadvantages in putting code into a VBA Userform instead of into a "normal" module?**

This might be a simple question but I have not found a conclusive answer to it while searching the web and stackoverflow.

**Background:** I am developing a Front-End Application of a database in Excel-VBA. To select different filters I have different userforms. I ask what general program design is better: **(1) putting the control structure into a separate module** OR **(2) putting the code for the next userform or action in the userform**.

Lets make an example. I have a Active-X Button which triggers my filters and my forms.

**Variant1: Modules**

In the CommandButton:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  call UserInterfaceControlModule
End Sub
```

In the Module:

```
Sub UserInterfaceControllModule()
Dim decisionInput1 As Boolean
Dim decisionInput2 As Boolean

UserForm1.Show
decisionInput1 = UserForm1.decision

If decisionInput1 Then
  UserForm2.Show
Else
  UserForm3.Show
End If

End Sub
```

In Variant 1 the control structure is in a normal module. And decisions about which userform to show next are separated from the userform. Any information needed to decide about which userform to show next has to be pulled from the userform.

**Variant2: Userform**

In the CommadButton:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

In Userform1:

```
Private Sub ToUserform2_Click()
  UserForm2.Show
  UserForm1.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
  UserForm2.Show
  UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

In Variant 2 the control structure is directly in the userforms and each userform has the instructions about what comes after it.

I have started development using method 2. If this was a mistake and there are some serious drawbacks to this method I want to know it rather sooner than later.

Comment: Take a look here: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/ . It explains a number of important differences between "Smart UI" and an MVP design pattern.

Comment: This is going to be fun... buckle up, you're in for a ride (answer in progress, give me a couple of hours).

Comment: @Mat'sMug better fix some of the Rubberduck issues instead ;)

Comment: While Mat's Mug is working on the answer you can look at how similar programming tasks were tackled by other people at Code Review (f.eks.: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form/154813#154813), [or here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58348/down-the-rabbit-hole-with-mvp) )

Comment: KISS is always my motto.  "keep it simple scripter" -  The reason is that you don't want to go back a year from now to fix a bug and try to decipher what macro does what for which form or sheet button.  Each userform should have a specific function, should be named accordingly, should have all macros inside of it - even if repetitious with another macro somewhere else.  (Unless it is a common macro, like finding last used row or common search function.)  And above all document, document, document.

Comment: @JohnMuggins I respectfully disagree. A "simple" form has no business caring anything whatsoever about the last used row of a given worksheet.

Comment: As I said - functions like that would be the exception.  I think you meant to say that you agree.

Comment: @PortlandRunner so design patterns are good and objectively presented as better or worse alternatives for every language, but because it's VBA, it's different? No. Smart UI is an anti-pattern regardless of the language, and understanding the responsibilities of every component of a program that involves a UI is fundamental to writing objectively maintainable and scalable code. This isn't opinion-based at all.

Comment: @PortlandRunner simple: because both alternatives in the OP strongly imply a "Smart UI" pattern, and involve the forms' default instances, which is THE single most common reason behind every single UserForm global state -related bug ever asked on Stack Overflow with VBA code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Okay, fair enough.  I'll delete my comments and remove the close vote.  Cheers.

Comment: I think it is largely subjective due to each programmers level of ability.  As I've said for me personally it is better to keep all code performed by the userform inside that particular userform's module - so that when I look at it 6 months from now I can come up to speed quicker.  A lot of times I may want to use or modify that same code for a new project.  Someone with a better memory of things might be better able to keep track of macros scattered about in different modules.  But not me.  We are not all the same level of ability.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, that's exactly what I was saying.  We all have different levels of ability.  What is Rubberduck?  An addin?

Comment: @JohnMuggins it's a free & open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage. The linked article at the top of this comment thread is on the project's blog.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually been looking for a transferable addin to keep a hundred or so functions available.  Don't think my employer will allow a commercial addin though.

Comment: @JohnMuggins - I use Rubberduck... it's worth pushing for it!

Comment: @VictorK just realized, ..these two CR links you put up there... I, uh... I authored them both lol. FWIW one of the perhaps most useful code I put up on CR is [this reusable progress indicator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87818/23788), which illustrates exactly what steering away from "Smart UI" mindset does to VBA code... I've been using that progress indicator in every VBA project I needed it ever since, *as-is*, without making any changes. A "Smart UI" implementation would have required massive code-behind changes to be anywhere near reusable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've been studying a number of CR and SO questions regarding these issues and gradually transferring my code to Interfaces/class modules. The "Indicator" as well as [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045940/8597922) were the most useful to distill the essence of the MVP out of the examples for me (thank you!). As a personal note - after learning VBA out of need to solve problems it is hard to change mindset to learn (a little) more of an actual OO programming. [It is almost as if Dijkstra was right](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7747)

Comment: @VictorK dang, I forgot about that answer. Oh well - I guess it can't hurt to have this knowledge splattered everywhere relevant on SO =)  FWIW I learned programming with BASIC 2.0 on a Commodore 64, then VB4/5/6, VBA, *and then .NET showed me the light*, and I'm trying to apply as much as possible of what I learned in .NET, to COM and VBA. The irony is that COM is inherently object-oriented, but VBA seems to do everything it can to hide it!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> **Disclaimer** I wrote the [article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) Victor K [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288496/are-there-disadvantages-in-putting-code-into-userforms-instead-of-modules#comment81527590_47288496). I own that blog, and manage the open-source VBIDE add-in project it's for.

Neither of your alternatives are ideal. Back to basics.

---

> *To select different filters I have differnt (sic) userforms.*

Your specifications demand that the user needs to be able to select different filters, and you chose to implement a UI for it using a `UserForm`. So far, so good... and it's all downhill from there.

Making the form responsible for anything other than *presentation concerns* is a common mistake, and it has a name: it's the *Smart UI* [anti-]pattern, and the problem with it is that **it doesn't scale**. It's great for prototyping (i.e. make a quick thing that "works" - note the scare quotes), not so much for anything that needs to be maintained over years.

You've probably seen these forms, with 160 controls, 217 event handlers, and 3 private procedures closing in on 2000 lines of code each: that's how badly *Smart UI* scales, and it's the only possible outcome down that road.

You see, a `UserForm` is a class module: it defines the *blueprint* of an *object*. Objects usually want to be *instantiated*, but then someone had the genius idea of granting all instances of `MSForms.UserForm` a *predeclared ID*, which in COM terms means you basically get a global object for free.

Great! No? No.

> ```
> UserForm1.Show
> decisionInput1 = UserForm1.decision
>
> If decisionInput1 Then
>   UserForm2.Show
> Else
>   UserForm3.Show
> End If
> ```

What happens if `UserForm1` is "X'd-out"? Or if `UserForm1` is `Unload`ed? If the form isn't handling its `QueryClose` event, the object is destroyed - but because that's the *default instance*, VBA automatically/silently creates a new one for you, just before your code reads `UserForm1.decision` - as a result you get whatever the initial global state is for `UserForm1.decision`.

If it wasn't a *default instance*, and `QueryClose` wasn't handled, then accessing the `.decision` member of a destroyed object would give you the classic run-time error 91 for accessing a null object reference.

`UserForm2.Show` and `UserForm3.Show` both do the same thing: fire-and-forget - whatever happens happens, and to find out exactly what that consists of, you need to dig it up in the forms' respective code-behind.

In other words, the **forms are running the show**. They're responsible for collecting the data, presenting that data, collecting user input, *and doing whatever work needs to be done with it*. That's why it's called "Smart UI": the UI knows everything.

There's a better way. MSForms is the COM ancestor of .NET's WinForms UI framework, and what the ancestor has in common with its .NET successor, is that it works particularly well with the famous *Model-View-Presenter* (MVP) pattern.

---

#### The Model

That's your *data*. Essentially, it's *what your application logic need to know* out of the form.

- `UserForm1.decision` let's go with that.

Add a new class, call it, say, `FilterModel`. Should be a very simple class:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TModel
    SelectedFilter As String
End Type
Private this As TModel

Public Property Get SelectedFilter() As String
    SelectedFilter = this.SelectedFilter
End Property

Public Property Let SelectedFilter(ByVal value As String)
    this.SelectedFilter = value
End Property

Public Function IsValid() As Boolean
    IsValid = this.SelectedFilter <> vbNullString
End Function
```

That's really all we need: a class to encapsulate the form's data. The class can be responsible for some validation logic, or whatever - but it doesn't *collect* the data, it doesn't *present* it to the user, and it doesn't *consume* it either. It *is* the data.

Here there's only 1 property, but you could have many more: think one field on the form => one property.

The model is also what the form needs to know from the application logic. For example if the form needs a drop-down that displays a number of possible selections, the model would be the object exposing them.

---

#### The View

That's your form. It's responsible for knowing about controls, writing to and reading from the *model*, and... that's all. We're looking at a dialog here: we bring it up, user fills it up, closes it, and the program acts upon it - the form itself doesn't *do* anything with the data it collects. The model might validate it, the form might decide to disable its <kbd>Ok</kbd> button until the model says its data is valid and good to go, but **under no circumstances** a `UserForm` reads or writes from a worksheet, a database, a file, a URL, or anything.

The form's code-behind is dead simple: it wires up the UI with the model instance, and enables/disables its buttons as needed.

The important things to remember:

- `Hide`, don't `Unload`: the view is an object, and objects don't self-destruct.
- **NEVER** refer to the form's *default instance*.
- Always handle `QueryClose`, again, to avoid a self-destructing object ("X-ing out" of the form would otherwise destroy the instance).

In this case the code-behind might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type TView
    Model As FilterModel
    IsCancelled As Boolean
End Type
Private this As TView

Public Property Get Model() As FilterModel
    Set Model = this.Model
End Property

Public Property Set Model(ByVal value As FilterModel)
    Set this.Model = value
    Validate
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = this.IsCancelled
End Property

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    this.Model.SelectedFilter = TextBox1.Text
    Validate
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Validate()
    OkButton.Enabled = this.Model.IsValid
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    this.IsCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

That's literally all the form does. **It isn't responsible for knowing where the data comes from or what to do with it**.

---

#### The Presenter

That's the "glue" object that connects the dots.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim m As FilterModel
    Set m = New FilterModel
    With New FilterForm
        Set .Model = m 'set the model
        .Show 'display the dialog
        If Not .IsCancelled Then 'how was it closed?
            'consume the data
            Debug.Print m.SelectedFilter
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If the data in the model needed to come from a database, or some worksheet, it uses a class instance (yes, *another* object!) that's responsible for doing just that.

The calling code could be your ActiveX button's click handler, `New`-ing up the presenter and calling its `DoSomething` method.

---

This isn't everything there is to know about OOP in VBA (I didn't even mention interfaces, polymorphism, test stubs and unit testing), but if you want objectively scalable code, you'll want to go down the MVP rabbit hole and explore the possibilities truly object-oriented code bring to VBA.

---

#### TL;DR:

Code ("business logic") simply doesn't *belong* in forms' code-behind, in any code base that means to scale and be maintained across several years.

In "variant 1" the code is hard to follow because you're jumping between modules and the presentation concerns are mixed with the application logic: it's not the form's job to know what other form to show given button A or button B was pressed. Instead it should let the *presenter* know what the user means to do, and act accordingly.

In "variant 2" the code is hard to follow because everything is hidden in userforms' code-behind: we don't know what the application logic is unless we dig into that code, which now *purposely* mixes presentation and business logic concerns. That is *exactly* what the "Smart UI" anti-pattern does.

In other words variant 1 is slightly better than variant 2, because at least the logic isn't in the code-behind, but it's still a "Smart UI" because it's *running the show* instead of *telling its caller what's happening*.

In both cases, coding against the forms' default instances is harmful, because it puts state in global scope (anyone can access the default instances and do anything to its state, from anywhere in the code).

Treat forms like the objects they are: instantiate them!

In both cases, because the form's code is tightly coupled with the application logic and intertwined with presentation concerns, it's completely impossible to write a single unit test that covers even one single aspect of what's going on. With the MVP pattern, you can completely decouple the components, abstract them behind interfaces, isolate responsibilities, and write dozens of automated unit tests that cover every single piece of functionality and document exactly what the specifications are - without writing a single bit of documentation: *the code becomes its own documentation*.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Might ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) Recordsets also serve to decouple the form from the database?  (OP says back end is a database).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailled answer! I have one follow up question: I have several Listboxes which need to update after user input. For example if a user selects a filter type the options for the filter need to adjust. Is that now job of "The View" but it needs to access the database so where would updateing a selection belong?

Comment: In these cases the view constantly "talks" to the presenter, say, by raising an event (e.g. `FilterUpdated` - in .net you could use delegates) - the presenter handles that event and updates the model, and the view refreshes its data. By doing that you are now able to fire up and thoroughly test your view's logic with entirely made-up data that doesn't hit a database at all: the view doesn't need to care where its data is coming from =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug You say that View never reads from the database. In cases where the form lists have to be populated from a recordset, who should handle the reading/populating?

Comment: @VictorK it's the presenter's responsibility to "seed" the model from whatever data source it needs to use (although, I'd put an abstraction layer between the presenter and its data sources, so that I can write unit tests for it - but that's beyond the scope of this answer); it's as stated in the previous comment: you implement some callback mechanism (could even be the model itself broadcasting its properties changing, à la `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to keep the presenter responsible for coordinating the work that the view shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @SMeaden the problem with, say, a *disconnected* ADODB recordset, is that it introduces an ADODB dependency on your model. If what you need is a `Collection` of strings, or a number of instances of some data object (e.g. some `User` or `Person` class, with `FirstName`, `LastName`  properties, etc. - the view knows how to consume it), then you don't need a *recordset* per se. The fewer dependencies, the easier the code is to write tests against.

Comment: This answer only sheds light on the dis-advantages. Though IMHO you should never use a Smart UI in a "complex" application I think it is okay to do so in a "simple" application.
But based on the question this is the right answer as the TO is going to develop a complex app.

Comment: @Storax well the question *did* ask specifically about the disadvantages. And I *do* say word-for-word "It's great for prototyping", too. That's all it's good for though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. He asked for the disadvantages ;-)

Comment: I started to implement these techniques and I only now start appreciating this answer as much as it deserves it. Thank you A LOT!

Comment: Better late than never! ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon: with the help of this answer I have finally started to grasp how the MVP linkage works to keep the view and the logic separate.  I had never worked with OOP and as a result couldn't conceive of how a form could function as required if the OK button (for example) only hid the form. With the help of this answer I have built two working MVP examples, and it still seems like magic even when I know what it is doing. Do you consider MVP to be strictly an OOP pattern?  If not, how would one implement it without objects?

Comment: It's definitely OOP. *Model*, *View*, and *Presenter* are objects, as is every component of every OOP design pattern. Although, sometimes they're just interfaces. ...without objects, you're writing scripts and macros, not programs.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Would we need multiple PresenterClasses for multiple `UserForm`? Where would we store, say a `.Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbRed` color property, or a `UserForm` text box font, in the `Module`, `Presenter`...?

Comment: @Jose presentation concerns belong in the form's code-behind; the font of a TextBox control (or any control's properties) is purely a presentation concern - in fact the only thing that knows anything about form controls is the form itself. OTOH interacting with a worksheet isn't a presentation concern at all, more likely a side-effect of executing some command - the command can be encapsulated in its own class, with the presenter invoking its `Execute` method; if a command needs to pop another form, then it should indeed have its own presenter dependency, yes; one view per presenter.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon  thank you for clarifying the form controls. I know we can disable / enable certain button controls based off the task the user is performing. I guess my question was moreso, "Where would I put the code that dictates what form controls users see, based off the action their doing" would it go in a regular Module or in the PresenterClass? I know it wouldn't go in the "ModelClass" because this is essentially our blueprint of our form control, not responsible for hiding or displaying objects.

Comment: @Jose it *would* be the model's job to expose e.g. an `IsAdmin() As Boolean` property that the view can use to enable/disable or show/hide certain controls; the model never knows anything about any controls, indeed.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon. Got it, eg, an `IsUpdate() As Boolean` would show an update button if my user was updating an existing record, as opposed to showing an "Add Record" button on the form, right? Just read above how RubberDuck organizes all of this into folders for different Models, nice! Downloading tonight, my fear was having so many class modules for different userforms.