# VBA: How do you reference variables already created in another form?

Tags: vba

I know this question has been asked before, but when I try to apply it to my program it doesn't seem to work.

So, I have a program I put together in the last few weeks that figures out which machine works best for which job at my work. I figured out all the math and everything and only have to show the results on another premade form. I have about 5 variables to move.

How would I go about setting that up... Thanks a bunch in advance for any help you can give.

**Form Names:**
CLR_Calculator,
Result

**Variables**
*(All of these are made in CLR_Calculator and already have values):*
BestMachine,
MCR,
Type,
Material

[Form.Variable Method Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImRrc.png)

Comment: Isn't a userform (CLR_Calculator) an object and the variables can be accessed as CLR_Calculator.BestMachine, CLR_Calculator.MCR, etc....?

Comment: Alright, so how would I go about making global variables? Is that just setting up a public sub and making the variables in it?

Comment: I tried using that method (the Form.Variable one), but for some reason it just pops up an error.

Comment: UserForms are classes. You can expose them as properties. Manually instantiate the form, set the properties you want to pass, then show it.

Comment: So, I would do something like "Dim CLR_Calculator As Form"?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291028/4088852).

Comment: Ah! Thanks a ton :D