# Issue RunTime 91 Data-Entry

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having trouble with Run-Time error even though I've looked on several YouTube videos and online tutorials and I'm still getting Run-Time Error 91. It seems I'm not missing anything from the tutorials, but it seems I am. I've tried different codes as far as writing .Offset(1, 0), and stuff like that.
Any help is appreciated!

```
Dim nr As Double
Dim wsl As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

nr = wsl.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wsl.Cells(nr, 1).Value = Me.txtProdName.Value
wsl.Cells(nr, 2).Value = Me.txtInvJan.Value
wsl.Cells(nr, 3).Value = Me.txtSpJan.Value
wsl.Cells(nr, 4).Value = Me.txtQtyUnit.Value
wsl.Cells(nr, 5).Value = Me.txtQtyBox.Value
wsl.Cells(nr, 6).Value = Me.txtDateStamp.Value


Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Dim wsl` ending in the *letter* `l` and `Set ws1` ending in the *number* `1`.

Comment: `Unload Me` is bad practice - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291028/9245853)

Comment: `Option Explicit`. ***Always***

Comment: `Option Explicit`.... and meaningful, easy-to-read names.

Comment: They really should do something about that font...
thanks guys! It works!

Comment: @pinnerj - they have done something about that font: `Option Explicit`