# Populating a ComboBox using a ListBox from a second UserForm

Tags: vba, combobox, listbox, userform

I have a UserForm1 that contains a ComboBox with three items. When item #3 is selected, a new UserForm2 pops up. That UserForm2 contains a ListBox that is populated with many entries from a sheet. I want to be able to select one of those entries in the ListBox and then pass the selected entry from the ListBox to the ComboBox in UserForm1 (using a button in UserForm2).

My simplified code looks like this:

(UserForm1)

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item1"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item2"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item3"
End Sub

Sub ComboBox1_Click()
   If ComboBox1 = "Item3" Then
      Load UserForm2
      UserForm2.show
   End If
End Sub
```

(UserForm2)

```
Sub UserForm2_Initialize()
   ListBox.AddItem "Apple"
   ListBox.AddItem "Pear"
   ListBox.AddItem "Banana"
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   MyVal = ListBox                 'using .Value or .Text in this or the next line doesn't help
   UserForm1.ComboBox1 = MyVal
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

(Module1)

```
Public MyVal As String
```

As soon as I click the button to pass the value from the ListBox to the ComboBox1, I get a

> "Runtime '380' - invalid property value"

error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try dimming `MyVal` as a `Variant` and using `.List` ?

Comment: Adding .List to what object?

Comment: By the way:
It seems that before passing the MyVal to the ComboBox1, the program is running the "Sub UserForm1_Initialize()" again. At the end (I guess when it actually tries to pass the value) it crashes.
Why would it initialize again? I don't unload/close UserForm1.

Comment: Posted an answer to your UserForm re-initializing issue based on @MathieuGuindon 's fundamental article "UserForm1.Show?" and his numerous posts on Stack Overflow; hopefully to contribute to further understanding for at least these SO readers facing the same issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

You select data from a listbox using the `Column` property. Starting at 0.

```
MyVal = ListBox.Column(0) 'This will store the data in the first column of the selected row
```

Comment: I have tried that before and it didn't seem to help, I'm afraid...

Comment: Do you get the error on the line with `UserForm1.ComboBox1 = MyVal`

Comment: See above for some details. That is exactly the error line.

Answer (score 0):

**Refresh Combobox using listbox from second Userform**

> *"It seems that before passing the MyVal to the ComboBox1, the program is running the "Sub UserForm1_Initialize()" again."*

Apart from some typos (regarding both `UserForm_Initiate` syntaxes) your main issue is that by invoking the default instance of a(n existing) userform you get it reinstanciated. Especially trying to assign a value by referencing another userform's default instance (see UserForm2's code module) via

```
    UserForm1.ComboBox1 = MyVal
```

... **re-initializes** the default instance of UserForm1 and destroys any changes before.

**Modified example to understand the way (see code below)**

So delete the code line above in the 2nd Userform code module and call an instance of UserForm2 via function `YourChoice()` in the 1st one returning the found value `MyVal` as function result in order to stick as close as possible to your post using a "global" variable `MyVal`.  This would allow you to use instances of a UserForm and to get what you wanted.

**Further possible steps** - *(Not)tl;tr*

It's good use, however

- not only to instantiate a ("New") UserForm object instead of calling the form's default instance,

but

- to handle its `QueryClose` event to prevent rash termination,
- to decide upon a UserForm's life time by the calling code (regular or class module),
- to separate model logic (i.e.the data), view (i.e. the form) and presentation, aka MVP design pattern using the advanced possibilities of classes.

Generally you should prefer not to *unload* within the form's code behind - I didn't change that to leave the example comprehensible, but would recommend to study ►Mathieu Guindon's outstanding article ["UserForm1.Show?"](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for a first insight, better understanding and some ideas on the road.

*Citation*

A Userform is not only a *class*, but disposes of an internal pecularity - or to cite *Mathieu*:

> "`UserForm` is a class module: it defines the *blueprint* of an *object*. Objects usually want to be instantiated, but then someone had the genius idea of granting all instances of `MSForms.UserForm` a *predeclared ID*, which in COM terms means you basically get a global object for free."

*c.f. [Disadvantages in putting code into UserForms instead of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288496/are-there-disadvantages-in-putting-code-into-userforms-instead-of-modules/47291028#47291028)*

**Modified Example code**

- **UserForm1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UserForm_Initialize()             ' << typo: not UserForm1_Initialize !
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item1"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item2"
   ComboBox1.AddItem "Item3"
End Sub

Sub ComboBox1_Click()
   If ComboBox1 = "Item3" Then
      '''      Load UserForm2          ' << don't reference the default instance 
      '''      UserForm2.Show          ' << but
      ComboBox1.List(2) = yourChoice   '    make it a function call returning your choice
   End If
End Sub
```

- **UserForm2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UserForm_Initialize()               ' typo: not UserForm2_Initialize !
   ListBox1.AddItem "Apple"
   ListBox1.AddItem "Pear"
   ListBox1.AddItem "Banana"
End Sub

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Purpose: assign listbox value to variable (here: global; better: via class property)
    MyVal = ListBox1                    ' equals ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    '''   UserForm1.ComboBox1 = MyVal   ' << reinitializes the default instance of UF1 !!!
    Unload Me                           ' (better to make the calling function terminate the form instead)
End Sub
```

- **Example call**

*Side note:* - as close as possible to the OP and sticking to the global variable method as mentioned above to allow better comprehension (consider mentioned suggestions, too :-)

```
Option Explicit

Public MyVal As String                  ' here: global variable

Sub showMain()
With New UserForm1
    .Show vbModeless ' any mode allowed: 0-vbModeless  or 1-vbModal (default)
End With
End Sub

Function yourChoice$()
With New UserForm2
    .Show vbModal   ' or simply: .Show to allow a correct return of the function result
End With
yourChoice = MyVal  ' (a modeless form would execute any code before termination)
End Function
```

**Further link**
This post doesn't treat modeless forms; calling the 2nd Userform this way would need other logic - see
[Destroy a modeless UserForm instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly)