# AddItem not populating options in combo box

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following form. I've added each item as per `.AddItem ""`, however they are not populating in the `combobox` in the userform.

(This is in a separate module referring to the userform)

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIJq.png]

**Code**

```
 With frmForm

    .txtFirst.Value = ""
    .txtLast.Value = ""
    .txtYear.Value = ""

    .cmbSchool.Clear
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "Harvard"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "Northwestern"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "UCBerkley"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "Stanford"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "NYU"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "UoT"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "UBC"
    .cmbSchool.AddItem "RMC"

    End With
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where and how are you showing that form? You're populating the `cmbSchool` control on the form's *default instance*, which may or may not be the form you're showing. Consider `New`ing up the form and holding on to the object/instance as long as you need it - and make sure you populate the controls on the same object that you eventually invoke `.Show` on.

Comment: For what it's worth, if that's all there is to it, then that code could all be in the `Initialize` handler of the form's code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that within the UserForm code module you shouldn't reference the *form's default name* (think it as a blue print for further instances of this *class*), but the **current object instance** it is actually run - e.g. by prefixing controls with the `Me.` qualifier.

This does assume the code is moved into the form's own code module - the `Initialize` handler would be a good place for this.

**Ways to populate a UserForm Combobox**

**a) Populating via `.AddItem` method**

```
    With Me.cmbSchool                       ' don't refer to the form's default instance
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Harvard"
        .AddItem "Northwestern"
        .AddItem "UCBerkley"
        .AddItem "Stanford"
        .AddItem "NYU"
        .AddItem "UoT"
        .AddItem "UBC"
        .AddItem "RMC"
    End With
```

**b) Populating via array**

Choosing this approach by assigning an array directly to the box'es `.List` property, you can shorten code to:

```
    Dim SchoolList As Variant
    SchoolList = "Harvard,Northwestern,UCBerkley,Stanford,NYU,UoT,UBC,RMC"
    Me.cmbSchool.List = Split(SchoolList, ",")
```

---

**Edit due to comment/2020-03-30**

> "Can you define what you mean by instance?"

A *class* - and a UserForm only represents a special type of class modules - can be regarded as sort of *object template*.

A so called **instance** of the class object (based on all properties, methods and events provided by the UserForm|class) 
will be created at runtime as a ►`New` object with access to the "." properties , i.e. it's getting *'newed'* (possibly repeatedly) to the current object you have declared and set to memory.

If you prefer to call the procedure from a separate module (instead in the form's `UserForm_Initialize()` handler), you could *"hold on to the object/instance (as long as you need it)"* 
by formal object setting as shown below (alternatively: `Dim myFrm As New frmForm`).

**Example call in standard module**

```
Sub ShowFormExample()
Dim myFrm    As frmForm   ' declare myFrm as object type belonging to your form's class
Set myFrm = New frmForm   ' set myFrm as new object instance to memory

FillItems myFrm           ' << call procedure FillItems
                  ' or integrate code here: Dim .../ SchoolList = ... / myFrm.cmbSchool.List = ...

myfrm.Show                ' form's .Show-method;  argument equals vbModal by default

End Sub
```

**Procedure `FillItems`**

```
Sub FillItems(myFrm As UserForm)
With myFrm
    Dim SchoolList As Variant
    SchoolList = "Harvard,Northwestern,UCBerkley,Stanford,NYU,UoT,UBC,RMC"
    .cmbSchool.List = Split(SchoolList, ",")
End With
End Sub
```

**Recommended readings**

- [Are there Disadvantages in putting code into userforms instead of modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288496/are-there-disadvantages-in-putting-code-into-userforms-instead-of-modules/47291028?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.6047#47291028)
- [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)
- Modeless forms are discussed at [Destroy a modeless Userform instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly)

Comment: In the question,the OP says "This is in a separate module referring to the userform". If that's the case they would need to create an instance of the form. I can't tell if frmForm is such an instance, or just the base UserForm that they've renamed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you define what you mean by instance? frmForm is the property name of the user form.

Comment: @DougGlancy - you're right, overread the last sentence in brackets. Will be editing tomorrow.