# Reuse UserForm after unloading and showing it

Tags: excel, vba, loading, userform

I'm trying to make a time and attendance.

I use two Userforms. UserForm1 where, with your id, you get to your sheet and can then clock in or clock out on UserForm2.

When you clock in or clock out, it goes back to UserForm1. Then UserForm1 doesn't work then anymore.
I tried loading, hide, show, exit sub.

Don't mind Names of Strings and stuff, it is a test.

I'm using the modulobject for the code so I'm referring in Userform1 Objects to a sub in the modullib.

**Modul1:**

```vb
Function DoesSheetExists(sh As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExists = True
End Function

Sub ScanID()
Dim MitarbeiterWS As Worksheet
Dim MitarbeiterID As Range
Dim MitarbeiterIDstring As String
Dim MitarbeiterName As String

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MitarbeiterID").Activate

MitarbeiterIDstring = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

Set MitarbeiterID = Range("A1:A30").Find(What:=MitarbeiterIDstring)

If Not MitarbeiterID Is Nothing Then
    MitarbeiterName = MitarbeiterID.Offset(, 1).Value
    UserForm1.Label1 = MitarbeiterName

    If Not DoesSheetExists(MitarbeiterName) Then
        If Not MitarbeiterName = "" Then
            Sheets("Example").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = MitarbeiterName
        
            Unload UserForm1
            UserForm2.Show
            MitarbeiterID.Select
            
        Else
        End If
    
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MitarbeiterName).Activate
        Unload UserForm1
        UserForm2.Show  
            
    End If

Else    
End If

End Sub
```

**Modul2**

```
Sub Eincloggen()
Dim Einspalte As Range

Set Einspalte = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

'wenn zum ersten mal eingeclockt
If Einspalte.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then
    If Einspalte.Value = "Clocked In" Then
        Einspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value = Now
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Erst Raus"
    
    End If

Else
    Einspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value = Now

    Unload UserForm2
    UserForm2.Hide
    UserForm1.Show

End If
End Sub

Sub Auscloggen()
Dim Einspalte As Range
Dim Ausspalte As Range
Dim Pausenspalte As Range
Dim Stundenspalte As Range

Set Einspalte = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set Ausspalte = Range("B1").End(xlDown)
Set Pausenspalte = Range("C1").End(xlDown)
Set Stundenspalte = Range("D1").End(xlDown)

If Ausspalte.Offset(1, -1).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Erst Rein"

Else
    Ausspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value = Now
    If Not Ausspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        Stundenspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value = (Ausspalte.Offset(1, 0).Value) - (Einspalte.Value)
        Stundenspalte.Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

        Unload UserForm2
        UserForm2.Hide
        UserForm1.Show

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you went with [variant 1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47288496/1188513); the answer there should help explain what's going on.

Comment: I tried your code and couldn't reproduce the error. How are you invoking the subs, by command buttons ? Does this need 2 forms ? I would have thought 1 form hiding and showing controls would suffice. The selection of person could be using a listbox or combobox.

Comment: Even if i try simple good with smart Ui like below the new userform doesnt do anything. If i type in the textbox it wont change the label. 
UserForm1:
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Label1 = TextBox1.Value
If Label1 = "Test" Then
UserForm1.Hide
UserForm2.Show
End If
End Sub

UserForm2:
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Label1 = TextBox1.Value
If Label1 = "Test" Then
UserForm2.Hide
UserForm1.Show
End If
End Sub